# Mapping App Engine Application to NON Google Apps Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps

I know this might be a duplicate question, but there was no ***precise*** answer to the question :

Can i map my appspot application URL to a non google apps domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise answer is no! If you want to use a custom domain, it has to be a Google Apps domain. See here for info -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: I believe you can create a Google Apps domain with 1 user for free, so long as you do it via the Add Domain button on the Application Settings page.

Comment: It used to be like that, but not anymore

Comment: @GwynHowell Apparently they are ["working on it"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM), you can ask for the USD 50 credit, though. The only workaround I know is [to add an alias domain to an existing Google Apps standard](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en), but you need to previously have registered. Hopefully with the new DNS as-a-service they announced they'll fix this issue.

Comment: @DavidCifuentes thanks for clarifying, I haven't tried it for a while. Good point about the DNS as a service - sounds like a good opportunity to improve on this

Answer (score 0):

Since today is now possible to assign any custom domain (no Google Apps required) to an App Engine app. In the [Google Cloud Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com), go to App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains

Google Apps is still required if you want to set up SSL via SNI.

See: https://plus.google.com/+RalfRottmann/posts/JNVz2TADgMb